# Device Owner "Kiosk" App boots before BOOT_COMPLETED and lock task replaces user lock screen for PIN password

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo, kiosk-mode, device-owner

I developed a Device Owner App (Full Kiosk) and in Lock Task Mode, that once installed on a provisioned device, it's instructed to set itself on the top of the screen.

Everything was fine until some day ago, when on some devices, after a firmware upgrade, an issue has come out.

- Device:  BlackView BV6000
- Android: 8 Oreo (API l. 26)

At the device boot (or re-boot), the app get opened itself on the PIN screen, above it, and so It stops the device boot as I cannot insert my PIN any more and it occupy the screen as main (and only) activity.

Normally, the boot sequence would be:

- LOCK_BOOT_COMPLETED
- BOOT_COMPLETED
- App start

but in this case the app would open itself in any case once the device has direct booted on the PIN lock screen.

The only receiver I have left in `manifest.xml` (I have removed all other receivers, but App still opens itself):

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="AlarmReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In my opinion, it would be caused by the fact that as an Alarm it's in the common case always awaiting to be delivered, once the device boots, my app receives the alarm intent, so it awakes the alarm receiver,  and in doing so, it for sure awake the whole App, that it would be set-up as Device Owner and in `lock task`mode so what I obtain is that my app gets in foreground over the PIN lock screen before I could actually do anything and force me to use it.

Additionaly, the  app is set up to be the launcher by following lines:

```
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        devicePolicyManager.addPersistentPreferredActivity(
                adminComponentName, intentFilter, new ComponentName(
                        context.getPackageName(), MyActivity.class.getName()));
```

Addirtionally, I make the keyguard disabled by:

```
devicePolicyManager.setKeyguardDisabled(adminComponentName, true);
```

My question is: **how can I prevent the app to get in foreground over the PIN lock screen?** I would like to make my app opening after the lock screen (on real BOOT_COMPLETE) but I don't have any clue about how to prevent the app to boot up once it gets the Alarm intent.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of investigations I found the origin of the issue.

The solutions is to do not open the app as the HOME app, so that it would override the PIN lock screen on some devices, instead it's important to bind it to be open on the desidered events (i.e. boot, reboot, default action, ...)

**Solution's implementation follows:**

I removed from my AdminController:

```
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```

*related to* `devicePolicyManager.addPersistentPreferredActivity(•)`

(and also add to be sure of proper reset)

```
devicePolicyManager.clearPackagePersistentPreferredActivities(
                adminComponentName, context.getPackageName());
```

and also removed from my manifest:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

> P.S. I found that the action BOOT_COMPLETED it's not always delivered correctly (even using it together with QUICKBOOT_POWERON), and so that's the reason I was using the CATEGORY_HOME intent.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my previous solution.

As the fact of the BOOT_COMPLETED doesn't triggers so affordably in Android system, also due to Android security policies, even if the app is in Device Owner COSU mode (lock task), I had to revert back to the CATEGORY_HOME intent.

So to solve my previous problem, I found that was caused by calling startLockTask when the app was in background under the PIN lock screen, and usually it would stayed on an activity under the screen. I just needed to add a check as follow to ensure that the app would be locked only if the screen is unlocked.

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( !myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() && MyApp.getInstance().isAppInForeground() ) {
    adminController.lockApp(this);
}
```